# Error while installing R's chron package

Tags: gcc, r

I am running R in ubuntu 14.04. 
Trying to install the package "chron" I get the following message:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c chron_strs.c -o chron_strs.o
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [chron_strs.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘chron’
```

gcc is installed and by querying cc1 I get:

```
$ sudo find /usr/ -name cc1*
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/help/stats/cc1.gif
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/cc1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/cc1
```

What is going on?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the command you used to install the package. Also show us the output of `which -a cc1`.

Comment: AFAIK each gcc should use its own version of cc1 which gets found using the programs path indicated by `gcc -print-search-dirs`. Ubuntu 14.04 should have gcc-4.8 by default, yet I see only 4.4 and 4.6 in your `find` result: what do `gcc --version` and `gcc -print-search-dirs` say? I suspect you're running gcc-4.8 but *its* cc1 has gone missing.

Comment: I run while inside R   >install.packages("chron")

Comment: No answer when I query cc1 (which -a cc1)

Comment: gcc --version >   gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: gcc -print-search-dirs
install: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/
programs: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../../......

Comment: Try reinstalling the `cpp-4.8` package. FYI it's better to [edit] your question with new information (instead of putting it in comments).